# Not able to reassign value to function parameter,while its not declared as val, val cannot be reassigned

Tags: android, function, kotlin

I am trying to write a function in kotlin but I am not able reassign value to function parameters ,its saying val cannot be reassigned .

```
class WebView{

    var homepage = "https://example.com"

    fun webViewLoad(url: String, preferredOrientation: String) {

            if (url.equals("homepage")){
                url = homepage
            }
        }
    }
```

when I am trying to assign a value to url = homepage .it is giving me error val cannot be reassigned ,  I am new to kotlin ,I do not understand what is the issue , little help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin function parameter: Val cannot be reassigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540035/kotlin-function-parameter-val-cannot-be-reassigned)

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin parameters are immutable since *Kotlin M5.1* 
 ([Reference](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/))

> The main reason is that this was confusing: people tend to think that this means passing a parameter by reference, which we do not support (it is costly at runtime). Another source of confusion is primary constructors: “val” or “var” in a constructor declaration means something different from the same thing if a function declarations (namely, it creates a property). Also, we all know that mutating parameters is no good style, so writing “val” or “var” infront of a parameter in a function, catch block of for-loop is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 3):

It is giving you error `"val cannot be reassigned"` because Kotlin function parameters are `immutable i.e "val" by default.` You don't need to mention the `"val" keyword` for it.

Quick Solution would be:

```
class WebView{

    var homepage = "https://example.com"

    fun webViewLoad(url: String, preferredOrientation: String) {
            val finalUrl = if (url.equals("homepage")) homepage else url
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters works like `val` variables that couldn't be reassigned. Here you need to add variable with conditional initialization:

```
fun webViewLoad(url: String, preferredOrientation: String) {
    val urlValue = if (url.equals("homepage")){
        homepage
    } else {
        url
    }
    ... //use here "urlValue" variable
}
```

By the way, in `kotlin` you don't need to use `equals` function to compare string: common operator `==` will be automatically replaced with `equals` in byte code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , but I do not understand , why its not working like java function .if url is variable than why i can not assign value to it ?

Comment: I'd say it's something like kotlin ideology. If it is so interesting for you, you can read about it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40563463/4762282) and comments to it.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin function parameters are final. There is no val or final keyword because that's the default (and can't be changed). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563406/final-or-val-function-parameter-or-in-kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

By default parameters passed in the function are final what you can do is to add var. Hope it helps.

```
fun webViewLoad(var url: String, preferredOrientation: String) {

            if (url.equals("homepage")){
                url = homepage
            }
        }
```