# How to change val to var in function kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin. I've got a problem with making a function that changes the value of the boolean.

```
fun main () {

    var x = false

    functionWithBoolean(variable = x)

}

fun functionWithBoolean(variable: Boolean) {

    if (variable){
        println("x is true, so I switch to false")
        variable = false //value of x should be changed from true to false
    }

    else if (variable == false){
        println("x is false, so I switch to true")
        variable = true //value of x should be changed from false to true
    }

}
```

The error I encountered: Kotlin: Val cannot be reassigned

Please for explanation how to make "variable" var, altough x is set for var.

Comment: For usual functions the params are always fixed (`val`). If you have complex logic that need saving of a other state you need to create a new local variable at the function scope (inside the function). So for you the variable `variable` is fixed. Because `variable` param is call-by-value you can overwrite `x` using return value inside the function and assigning it (`val result = sum(2,2)`). Collections can be changed without returnvalue because they are call-by-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = false
```

In this `x` can be reassigned

But when you pass the value as an argument to `functionWithBoolean` you are passing are reference and so even if you did change it, it won't alter the source.

However, if you pass back the value as a return via this simple change, you will achieve what you want:

```
    fun main () {
        var x = false

        x = functionWithBoolean(variable = x)
    }

    fun functionWithBoolean(variable: Boolean): Boolean {

        if (variable){
            println("x is true, so I switch to false")
            return false //value of x should be changed from true to false
        }

        else{ // you don't need:  if (variable == false)
            println("x is false, so I switch to true")
            return true //value of x should be changed from false to true
        } 

    }
```

Comment: why did you add an additional Boolean after declaring an argument? (7th line)

Comment: Because in my modification I am RETURNING a Boolean from the function, hence the two `return` statements within the function.

Not that there is NO relationship between the `x` at the beginning and the end of this line `x = functionWithBoolean(variable = x)` all of the following are also perfectly ok:
`x = functionWithBoolean(false); val y = functionWithBoolean(x); println(functionWithBoolean(x))`

Answer (score 1):

To change a variable in a function, you would have to pass an actual variable setter, not just the value of the variable. So you would have to give your function a variable-setting parameter. This is just an example of how you could actually achieve this. In most cases, this would be considered convoluted design.

I changed "variable" to "input" because it doesn't make sense to call your function parameter a variable. You cannot directly pass variables around, only values.

```
fun main () {

    var x = false

    functionWithBoolean(input = x, useNewValue = { x = it })

}

fun functionWithBoolean(input: Boolean, useNewValue: (Boolean)->Unit) {

    if (input){
        println("x is true, so I switch to false")
        useNewValue(false)
    }

    else if (input== false){
        println("x is false, so I switch to true")
        useNewValue(true)
    }

}
```

This design is convoluted and error-prone, so usually you would simply return a new value from the function and assign it to your variable:

```
fun main () {

    var x = false

    x = functionWithBoolean(input = x)

}

fun functionWithBoolean(input: Boolean): Boolean {

    return if (input){
        false
    }

    else {
        true
    }

}
```

Or more simply:

```
fun functionWithBoolean(input: Boolean): Boolean {
    return !input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing the variable x into a function, you pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference  you can imagine that a copy is passed. You might find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540035/kotlin-function-parameter-val-cannot-be-reassigned) (the same problem, posted Mar 1, 2017) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156632/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-main-function-to-another-function-and-modify-it-ko), but normally you would not change the parameter value from a function.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689951/15749574)

Comment: And you often need to modify that copy, for example: reading/writing LEB128, and kotlin forces you to add a redeclaration as a var that results in an annoying shadowed warning

Answer (score 0):

I find other answers sort of correct with this, val cannot be reassigned directly and there are some valid solutions about that. I also found that things with var properties can have those properties changed and they stay changed outside of functions.

This includes Array, List, and DoubleArray. In a function array[0] may be changed and used but you can't assign array unless it is a var property of something, use a BooleanArray for simplicity.

```
fun main () {

    var x = BooleanArray(1){false};

    functionWithBoolean(x)

}

fun functionWithBoolean(variable: BooleanArray) {

    if (variable[0]){
        println("x is true, so I switch to false")
        variable[0] = false //value of x should be changed from true to false
    }

    else if (variable[0] == false){
        println("x is false, so I switch to true")
        variable[0] = true //value of x should be changed from false to true
    }
}
```