# How can I make a CompletableDeferred incomplete again after completing it?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val shouldRetry = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        flow {
            for (x in 1..10) {
                if (x == 2)
                    throw Throwable()

                emit(x)
            }
        }.retryWhen { _, _ ->
            Log.w("L384", "retryWhen")
            delay(750)
            shouldRetry.await()
            true
        }.collect {
            Log.w("L384", "$it")
        }

        val retryBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn)
        retryBtn.setOnClickListener {
            shouldRetry.complete(Unit)
        }
    }
}
```

When an upstream throws an exception, the retryWhen function will not retry until the user clicks on the button, and that is what I want. However, after the user clicks on the button, the retries will automatically be called without waiting for the next click, because the await function is completed. The question is, how can I, when completing the CompletableDeferred, make it incomplete again?

Is CompletableDeferred the best choice for this purpose, or is there something else that would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't make already completed deferred/job incomplete. However, we can easily create a new deferred.

I'm not exactly sure at which point in time you would like to make the retry button active. From your example it looks like the user could click "retry" even before the exception happens and then it would apply to the next error. I'll assume the button should work only when the error already happened, so when it waits for the user input:

```kotlin
    var shouldRetry = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        flow {
            for (x in 1..10) {
                if (x == 2)
                    throw Throwable()

                emit(x)
            }
        }.retryWhen { _, _ ->
            Log.w("L384", "retryWhen")
            shouldRetry = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()
            // enable button
            delay(750)
            shouldRetry.await()
            // disable button
            true
        }.collect {
            Log.w("L384", "$it")
        }

        val retryBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn)
        retryBtn.setOnClickListener {
            shouldRetry.complete(Unit)
        }
    }
```

Initial deferred isn't used, you can replace it with a null if you like.

Enabling/disabling the button is optional. There is a kind of race condition between the flow collector and click listener, but I believe it can't do any harm here.

Also, because you don't return anything from the deferred, you can use `Job()` instead.

Comment: Inside `retryWhen`, Why don't you add a condition before `shouldRetry = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()`? It would be like `if (shouldRetry.isCompleted) shouldRetry = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()`. Do you think the condition would be useless in this context?

Comment: @TahaSami How would that improve the code? I think this is unnecessary and it adds complexity to the code. Also, that condition is always true except for the first error. If I would like to optimize to not throw away that first deferred, then I would rather use null initially as this is clearer.

Comment: Everything works well, but there's a problem when trying to apply the MVVM pattern. The issue arises when passing a `CompletableDeferred` as an argument to a function in the repository class. The problem is that Kotlin automatically changes the var parameter to val, making it impossible to modify the source.

Comment: You might suggest returning the value as a function return, but that's not feasible because I need to use it with something else. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this? Take a closer look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972910/how-to-change-val-to-var-in-function-kotlin) for additional details about the problem.

Comment: I'm considering creating a separate function inside the repository to return `CompletableDeferred`. However, do you think there might be a better solution?

Comment: I made a change by moving the `shouldRetry` variable from inside the `onCreate` method to the repository class. I also created a new function within the repository. Now, when the user clicks on the button, it triggers this function. The function completes its task and generates a new instance. Everything is working smoothly now. Thanks, broot!